# "jhipster gae" deploys the backend, but not the Angular side

Tags: jhipster

Once the jhipster app is deployed to GCP the web site says:
An error has occurred :-(.
It is the error you get when you run "mvnw", but not "npm start".

I create a monolithic Spring and Angular 8 application with jhipster 6.2.0.
I run the "jhipster gae" command and answer the prompts.
I run the "./mvnw appengine:deploy -DskipTests -Pprod,prod-gae" command on my Ubuntu 18.0.4 OS.
It deploys successfully, kind of.  I don't get any errors on the command prompt, but when I get to the URL I get the message, "An error has occurred :-(".
It basically says that I didn't run "npm start".  So it is like it ran "mvnw", but not "npm start".

Comment: This error message does not apply. Have a look at the requests that fail in Chrome dev tools. Check whether the upload jar contains the js bundle of your angular app.

Comment: If I run, "sudo ./mvnw", then when I check localhost:8080 the web site is working as expected.  If I run "sudo ./mvnw appengine:run -DskipTests" and check my local host I get that error page.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions? Please edit your question with details collected. So far you haven't answered about what you see in Chrome (console and network) and about unzipping executable jar to check for js bundle. I don't use gcp so I don't know if it uses maven prod profile to bundle the frontend. If it does not then it's normal to get this error and maybe you need to explicilty build the frontend with webpack.